# JOIN multiple queries from same table into one result

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a question in a practical for university but can't figure out how to achieve the output I need. I am relatively new to SQL and am using Oracle 11g.

I have a single table called CUSTOMERS that I want to run three queries on to get the total count from each

`CUSTOMERS (customer#, lastname, firstname, address, city, state, zip, referred, region)`

The three queries on their own execute fine and produce the desired result but I need to find a way to combine them to produce a single result with three columns and the result of each query in each column.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Total Customers" 
FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Direct Customers" 
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE referred IS NOT NULL;
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Referred Customers" 
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE referred IS NULL;
```

I have spent the last few hours reading here and other sites but just can't get my head around it. I suspect a JOIN or UNION may be required.

Comment: You don't need a join or union here; just use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single query with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "Total Customers",
    COUNT(referred) AS "Direct Customers",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN referred IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS "Referred Customers"
FROM CUSTOMERS;
```